# Is it possible to create a non resizable hashtable in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures

Python doesnt have built in fixed size arrays, all arrays are resizable in python. A hashtable uses arrays because they have a fixed size for efficiency. Pythons list auto resizes, this is a costy operation which in my opinion eliminates part of upside of using hashtables because of their efficiency. Is there a way to make fixed size hashtables in python?

Comment: Just an immutable hashtable (dict?) or a performant immutable hashtable?

Comment: Something like this? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict/

Comment: "Python doesnt have built in fixed size arrays" untrue btw, instances of `bytes` are immutable arrays (Python 3's docstring says so explicitly).

Comment: Resizing the dict is a win if you look for things more often than you add them. What would you like to happen when adding an element that would cause a resize?

Comment: @timgeb not to mention the `array` module.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not provide a way to prevent resizing of dicts.